# How to access JS Object value in nestted object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am having trouble accessing the data in this JS Object.  I can get this data by accessing *data.queryParams*.  But if I try to drill lower, I get *undefined*.  Below is what shows up if I do a JSON.stringify(data.queryParams).  I've tried data.queryParams.attributes, data.queryParams[0], data.queryParams.handle, etc.  And I get undefined for all of them.

**console.log(data)**

```
Object {
  "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
  "path": null,
  "queryParams": Object {
    "{\"attributes\":[{\"handle\":\"email\",\"name\":\"Email\",\"value\":\"test@test.com\"},{\"handle\":\"fname\",\"name\":\"First Name\",\"value\":\"Luke\"},{\"handle\":\"lname\",\"name\":\"Last Name\",\"value\":\"Skywalker\"},{\"handle\":\"zip\",\"name\":\"Postal Code\",\"value\":\"73067-9895\"},{\"handle\":\"uuid\",\"name\":\"Unique Identifier\",\"value\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXX\"}],\"status\":[{\"group\":\"penguins\",\"subgroups\":[\"King penguins\"],\"verified\":true}]}": "",
  },
  "scheme": "exp",
}
```

**console.log(data.queryParams)**

```
Object {
  "{\"attributes\":[{\"handle\":\"email\",\"name\":\"Email\",\"value\":\"test@test.com\"},{\"handle\":\"fname\",\"name\":\"First Name\",\"value\":\"Luke\"},{\"handle\":\"lname\",\"name\":\"Last Name\",\"value\":\"Skywalker\"},{\"handle\":\"zip\",\"name\":\"Postal Code\",\"value\":\"73067-9895\"},{\"handle\":\"uuid\",\"name\":\"Unique Identifier\",\"value\":\"42e97018b6604fe491b82b629ad65c23\"}],\"status\":[{\"group\":\"penguins\",\"subgroups\":[\"King penguins\"],\"verified\":true}]}": "",
}
```

Comment: try without `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Its because I already drilled down into that object.  Thats the farthest I can do.  *data* has to 4 elements: data.path, data.hostname, data.scheme, and data.queryParams.  queryParams is the only one thats an object

Comment: i think the `queryParams` is already JSON so try without `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Show a [example].

Comment: Although looks like that you need `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @user202729 I've tride JSON.parse on *data.queryParams* but I get: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object". Because it is already an object.

Comment: Looks like that you're doing something wrong in the code that generates the data...? Show that too.

Comment: The data is being return from an Oauth authentication process. This is in React Native, but that should not matter since this is basic JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think something wrong with your response, your data is set as key of the Object.

```js
const obj = {
  "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
  "path": null,
  "queryParams": {
    // below is your data as key
    "{\"attributes\":[{\"handle\":\"email\",\"name\":\"Email\",\"value\":\"test@test.com\"},{\"handle\":\"fname\",\"name\":\"First Name\",\"value\":\"Luke\"},{\"handle\":\"lname\",\"name\":\"Last Name\",\"value\":\"Skywalker\"},{\"handle\":\"zip\",\"name\":\"Postal Code\",\"value\":\"73067-9895\"},{\"handle\":\"uuid\",\"name\":\"Unique Identifier\",\"value\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXX\"}],\"status\":[{\"group\":\"penguins\",\"subgroups\":[\"King penguins\"],\"verified\":true}]}": "",
  }, 
  "scheme": "exp",
};

let value = Object.keys(obj.queryParams)[0]; // <-- get your data
value = JSON.parse(value); // <-- set to JSON

console.log(value.attributes) // <-- test log attributes
```

but better if you can fix the response

Comment: Thanks @Rap Sherlock.  This was it.  I've been at this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSON.parse to convert your JSON string to an object, then you can access your data

```js
let attributes = JSON.parse(data.queryParams).attributes;
console.log(attributes)
```

Comment: That does not work. *data* is what I named the variable.  I still get undefined.  I'm going to update this with the full data variable.

Comment: I get the following: *JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
* [native code]:null in parse*